# Frequency error when running Holt-winter's seasonal method in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying out time series analysis on R using the "Unemployment Rate" data of the US_indicators dataset in the TSstudio package. As the dataset originally exists as a data.frame, I tried turning it into a xts object before applying it to some time series model (in this case, a holt-winter's damped additive model). The codes I have used as are follows:

```
# packages
library(TSstudio)
library(xts)
library(forecast)
    
# xts
unemployment_xts <- xts(x=US_indicators$"Unemployment Rate", order.by=US_indicators$Date, frequency=12)
fc_xts <- hw(unemployment_xts, damped=TRUE, seasonal="additive")
frequency(unemployment_xts)
```

However, I was prompted that the "time series should have frequency greater than 1". When I checked the xts object's frequency, I realize that it was "1" although I specified in the argument that the frequency should be "12". May I enquire why is this so? And what should I have done instead so as to correctly run the time series model on the data? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consecutive Date class dates always have a frequency of 1 since consecutive dates are 1 apart. `xts` does not support this. A quick `ts(xts.object, frequency=12, start = 1976)` call when passing to forecast functions takes care of the frequency issue.

```
# xts
unemployment_xts <- xts(x=US_indicators$"Unemployment Rate", order.by=US_indicators$Date, frequency=12)
fc_xts <- hw(ts(unemployment_xts, frequency = 12, start = 1976), damped=TRUE, seasonal="additive")
frequency(ts(unemployment_xts, frequency = 12, start = 1976))
```

Comment: hello, thank you!